# What does the phrase "humor me" mean?

Tags: phrases

I've never understood the term "humor me". Is it meant sarcastically? Please explain.

Comment: [Humour](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humour?q=humour) is a verb there.

Comment: is it used sarcastically sometimes? Last night I was watching constantine, in that hero uses this often..

Comment: Any utterance can be used sarcastically.

Comment: General Reference. [Humour](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/humor) *Verb (used with object) to comply with the humour or mood of in order to soothe or make content or more agreeable*

Comment: @FumbleFingers That was my initial reaction, too; but on consideration it appears to me that pahnin is asking for something which that definition does not address.

Comment: @StoneyB: I've no idea what "constantine" is, or how the hero there uses the expression. But I don't see how your posted answer adds anything to the dictionary definitions in links posted by me and Matt.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  With respect to "constantine" - me neither. That's pahnin's comment. With respect to the definitions - they don't address pahnin's question about how the specific catchphrase "humor me" is used.

Comment: @StoneyB: I wouldn't call it a "catchphrase", and I still don't see any significant difference in meaning between your definition and, say, Dickens' usage in [Oliver Twist](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5CBIFULR7UAC&pg=PA269&lpg=PA269&dq=%22to+humour+me+well+well%22&source=bl&ots=fJNjQumsLP&sig=UxzZsQAJRntmgdW5sIOjJWk30dQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VPYwUJaCMYmb1AWNioDgDA&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20humour%20me%20well%20well%22&f=false) 150 years ago.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Perhaps there is a better technical term; discourse analysis had not yet reached lit crit when I left academe. But pahnin's comment, and my own experience, mark "Humor me" as a free-standing linguistic chunk whose use is not entirely defined by it's dictionary meaning - and which is quite different from the condescending use of "humor you" to which the girl in your passage responds. *You* see the path from the one to the other; pahnin only *suspects* the path, and asks for confirmation: "Is it meant sarcastically?" It is that to which both Adam and I respond.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Humor*, as a verb, means literally to indulge or tolerate someone's *humor* (noun), where the noun intends not the modern sense of  *joking* or a transient *mood* but the now archaic sense of *temperament* or *idiosyncracy* or *eccentricity*.

*Humor me* thus means *indulge me*—in the sense of *gimme some slack* or *gimme a break*, but less aggressive than these. It is used most often as an appeal, at once gentle and ironic, to an interlocutor who interrupts one's discourse; it means, approximately, *Let's treat what I'm saying* (or doing) *and you're objecting to as mere personal whim—on that basis, allow me to finish, and then you can have your say.*

Comment: To clarify, this usage of 'humor' as a verb is not archaic; it is very common. The noun isn't that archaic either, but the ideas behind seem from a former age.

Comment: @Mitch  Thank you; I thought I'd sufficiently restricted my attribution of 'archaic' to the noun, but I'll rewrite. I believe that the original sense of permanent character has been in almost entirely replaced in contemporary use by the sense of transient attitude, except ambiguously in such derivatives as "good-humored". We no longer say "He's a man of irascible humor", but we do say "He was in a good humor yesterday."

Answer (score 10):

*"Hey, friend. Can I get you to stand right here under this teetering bucket of water?"*

*"Why?"*

*"Humor me."*

*"Oh, alright."*

In my opinion, it isn't necessarily sarcastic, it's simply a way of saying: *"Just comply with what I'm saying/doing right now and you can contradict me later."*